# What's the excuse in GTA IV to close some parts of city?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

In GTA 3 the excuse to close the bridge was a bomb.

In GTA IV, what's the excuse?
I just don't understand why they should kill me
The radio said something about it, but I was busy and did not listen the full sentence

Comment: "Security". Sorry, that's a single word, not a reason for the restrictions you're placing on my freedom. Could you be more specific? "Security." Right. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The excuse is a **terror alert**; it is mentioned on the radio, both on the news and during the talk shows.

Found this as reference (just listen to the start):

Comment: thanks! as a non-english speaker, i am a little impaired to listen this fast stuff...